# Why does my loop only print Negative numbers when there is no condition?

Tags: java, infinite-loop

Like-

Here the compiler is printing Negative numbers-

```
    for(short a = 1; ; a++)
    System.out.println(a);
```

But, here the compiler is not printing any negative numbers. It's printing the maximum value of the short data type and then not printing the negative numbers-

```
    for(short a = 1;a<= -2 ; a++)
    System.out.println(a);
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please debug it. First loop is also printing Positive numbers along with negative.

Comment: @Haiyanman consider INT instead of SHORT

Comment: I assume you're also getting positive numbers, which then become negative. That's because without a condition the loop will loop forever, and eventually you'll overflow. In Java, an overflow wraps around to the smallest value possible. In other words, your loop reaches `Short.MAX_VALUE` and then the next increment wraps around to `Short.MIN_VALUE` (a negative number) and you increase from there.

Comment: @Slaw Yes, I am getting Positive as well as negative numbers. Thanks for your Explanation!

Comment: Utilising the wrap-around from Short.MAX_VALUE to Short.MIN_VALUE is not a very good idea, as it is not obvious to the reader what you expect to happen. Good coding practice suggests that either you code what you want the loops to do without using a side-effect such as this, or at least document what is happening.

Answer (score 4):

First, I think you should check this code:

```
for(short a = 1; ; a++)
System.out.println(a);
```

as the loop start from numbers from 1, increase to 2, then to 3, and so on, until it reaches Short.Max_value, then turn back into Short.Min_value and so on. In each iteration, it continues simply because the conditions are hold in every cases

Second, this code:

```
for(short a = 1;a<= -2 ; a++)
 System.out.println(a);
```

does not actually print out anything, since, it print out all numbers from 1 to -2. Or to other saying, you start from 1, but before the start of next iteration, it compares 1 <= -2, which is `false` and thus stops the loop.

Comment: The first loop will eventually increment `a` to `Short.MAX_VALUE`, and then the next iteration will cause an overflow to `Short.MIN_VALUE`. That's where the negatives come from.

Comment: I forgot about that case, since my compiler has an early termination. Thank you very much for that. Fixed my answer

Comment: *"my compiler has an early termination"* - What?  If your compiler is generating code that doesn't output negative numbers, then it is not Java compliant.  I think you mean something else.

Comment: My compiler terminated after print out the number 1585, which is far from Short.Max_value

Comment: I think the point @StephenC is making is that the _compiler_ does not execute the code, and so if you're saying the _compiler_ outputs byte-code that alters the loop to terminate early then it's not a Java-compliant implementation. That is to say, what you're calling the compiler is likely not a compiler but something else.

Comment: (Yes.  That is what I am saying)